# Setting up structure map in a c# console application

Tags: c#, ioc-container, structuremap

I'm getting this error:

```
StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily
```

My setup looks like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Structure Map");
SetupSM sm = new SetupSM();
sm.Setup();

ISomeThing someThing = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISomeThing>();
Console.WriteLine("something.HowManyTHings: " + someThing.HowManyThings("asdf"));



 public class SetupSM
    {
        public void Setup()
        {
            var c1 = new Container(config =>
            {
                config.Scan(scan =>
                {
                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                });
            });

            var c2 = new Container(x =>
                                              {
                                                  x.For<ISomeThing>().Use<SomeThingOne>();
                                              });


        }
    }
```

This is my first try at using structure map, what am I missing?
It seems the guide on their main website is very old using the old syntax etc.

Comment: "It seems the guide on their main website is very old using the old syntax etc." StructureMap is kind of notorious for this.

Comment: You're using ObjectFactory to get the instance but you're configuring 2 entirely seperate containers. Try ObjectFactory.Configure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try applying your configuration to the static ObjectFactory instead of seperate containers which you appear to throw away immediately..

```
public class SetupSM
    {
        public void Setup()
        {
            ObjectFactory.Configure(config =>
            { 
                config.Scan(scan =>
                {
                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                });

                config.For<ISomething>().Use<SomeThingOne>();
            });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that did it!  So in a web application, I would just make this call to Setup() in my application begin request in global.asax file?

Answer (score 5):

The previous answers are for StructureMap 2 or 3, but in StructureMap 4 the syntax has changed. You can see a complete solution here:

http://ardalis.com/using-structuremap-4-in-a-console-app

Essentially, ObjectFactory has been replaced with a Container instance. You can also optionally perform the configuration in a separate Registry instance, which is recommended. Thus your initialization code in Main() becomes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = Container.For<ConsoleRegistry>();

    var app = container.GetInstance<Application>();
    app.Run();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This keeps Main very clean, and allows Application to request any dependencies it needs through [dependency injection](http://deviq.com/dependency-injection/) and to follow the [Explicit Dependencies Principle](http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/). Combined, these allow your application to be very composable and testable.

Comment: What about the `Application` class? We get it from the container, but never explicitly register it. Does its registration get handled by StructureMap's "Default Conventions"?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class StructureMapBootStrapper
{
    public static void BootStrap()
    {
        StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Initialize(
            bootStrapper =>
            {
                bootStrapper.For<ISomeThing>().Use<SomeThingOne>();
            });
    }
}
```

Your console app:

```
Console.WriteLine("Structure Map");
StructureMapBootStrapper.BootStrap();

ISomeThing someThing = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISomeThing>();
Console.WriteLine("something.HowManyTHings: " + someThing.HowManyThings("asdf"));
```